# Authorize attribute on ASP.net MVC return form without form tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I have view that works fine until i added Authorize attribute in the Create action in the productcontroller of Admin areas.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
ViewBag.Action = "Create";
VewBag.Category = new SelectList(this.categoryCoreModel.Categories, "CategoriaKy", "CategoriaDescIT");
ViewBag.SubCategory = new SelectList(this.subCategoryCoreModel.SubCategories, "CategoriaSubKy", "CategoriaSubDescIT");
return this.View("Create", new ProductEditModel ());
}
```

In my view

```
<div class="form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Action, "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { Model, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
         ...............
         .............
 }
```

My problem is when i click on Save button it redirects to another URL like Admin/Home which does not exists. And the Form tag is missing too. What I have been missing here?

Edited:
It seems after success login the loginpartial view renders form which is making mess with my product form.

```
  @(Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
```

Any idea or feedback would be great

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected to see [Authorize(Roles="SomeRoleName")] so that your authorize can prove that the user has the role, as you have not specified a role (and you might not actually be logged in) its redirecting you to where the role provider has specified i.e. in the loginUrl

Are you using SimpleRoleProvider like this?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="Models.SimpleRoleProvider, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

If so then the HttpContext.User.Identity and/or HttpContext.User.IsInRole is not returning what the [Authorize()] is expecting. I would advise you to look at the logon section and make sure that you are setting the user as logged and and that he/she has a role for authorize to latch onto

Hope this helps

Comment: I am not using role provider at all. I have user anonymous and authenticate. when i open /Admin/Product/Create it redirect to Account/Login as expected. After successfull login it redirect back to /Admin/Product/Create. Which seems fine. But when i post back using save button it dint work. as it redirect to somewhere else because my page does not have the form tag.

Comment: Are you separating out your methods with [httpget] and [httppost] attributes, and different signatures so that your routing knows where to put the httppost to? It might be that you need to provide a different signature and decorate the post with [httppost] and then set a breakpoint in the attribute so that you can prove that the routing is sending you to the right place

Comment: Yes, I have already set [httppost] attribute. but the view does not show any form tag after adding the Authorize attribute. It is working fine without Authorize  attibute